# How to test supported devices before pushing my app to the Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I have generated separate APK's for Tablet and Mobile phone versions with the  filters as recommended by the developer site.

```
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html
```

However, after successful rollout, showing 'Unsupported device' for few of the devices for multiple reasons.

Here, I want to test locally whether my application supports particular device or not before I push to play-store.

Can somebody help me here how I can test my app for 'Supported' on the particular device or not before I upload to Playstore?

PS: I have few physical devices available to me to test.

Comment: You already have few physical devices . For rest of sizes you can use AVD or [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: I don't really get your point, you declare in the manifest the features your app needs and the screen sizes it supports. The supported phones will then be determined according to these settings. It does not make sense to get more supported phones if the app does not work properly on them.

Comment: @ADM, I can able to install APK directly on the devices I have with me. But its showing "Device not supported" when I upload the same APK to play store.

Comment: Can you clarify your question by showing your app manifest, and details of the device which works when you install it manually, but the Play store says "Device not supported"?